# Exception while selecting template using Spring and Velocity. It is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, velocity

I am trying to send predefined HTML email template using **Spring** and **Velocity**. It is throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    null at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtils.java:53)~[spring-context-support-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE] 
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngineUtils.java:92) ~[spring-context-support-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE] 
    at com.incyyte.app.service.MailService.sendReactivationEmail(MailService.java:159) ~[classes/:na]
```

My function implemenation is shown below:

```
 public void sendReactivationEmail(Optional<User> user) {
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(user.get().getLangKey());
    String websiteURL = messageSource.getMessage("website.url", null, locale);
    String reactivationURL = websiteURL + messageSource.getMessage("activation.url", null, locale);
    String emailSubject = messageSource.getMessage("reactivation.subject", null, locale);
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("vmTemplate/Reactive_email.vm").getFile());
    Map<String, Object> emailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    emailModel.put("username", user.get().getLogin());
    emailModel.put("activationCode", reactivationURL + user.get().getActivationKey());
    emailModel.put("webURL", websiteURL);
    String content = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, file.getAbsolutePath(), emailModel);
    sendEmail(user.get().getEmail(), emailSubject, content, false, true);
}
```

I had seen the file absolute path and it is showing as

`D:\v2dev\incyyte_version2\appCode\target\classes\vmTemplate\Reactive_email.vm`

Here Reactive_email.vm is my email template in HTML format. I think this exception is coming because Velocity is not able to read the file. Please help me to trace this exception and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to load the template in a `File` before. You can directly use the method `mergeTemplateIntoString` with the path of the template.

Like this :

```
String content = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "vmTemplate/Reactive_email.vm", emailModel);
```

Make sure the templates is into the `src/main/resources` directory.

Hope it will help you